# Image Map for Weight Painter

Tags: texturing, particles, weight-painting, height-map

I am working on a jungle scene in blender and I was wondering if it was possible to somehow use the height map I used for the floor texture to control the weight map for grass distribution (so as to not have grass growing from puddles. I would like to keep the grass to the green non-muddy areas in the photo.) I understand I would need to tonvert the height map somehow but so far I have not seen any texture control for weight mapping.[image: jungle floor]